# How to run TFLint Docker - Passing multiple Args

Tags: docker, terraform, hcl

Running TFLint through their Docker Image [Here](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/pkgs/container/tflint) - I have to pass tflint multiple commands one after the other to initialize and run the tool which is where I'm running into issues

I have ran it locally using the following commands, which returns what I want:

```
tflint --init --config 'path/to/config/'
tflint --config 'path/to/config/config.tflint.hcl' 'path/to/terraform/code'

# AND

tflint --init --config 'path/to/config/config.tflint.hcl' && tflint --config 'path/to/config/' 'path/to/terraform/code'
```

Here are the commands I use to run the docker image:

```
docker run -it -v "$(pwd):/tflint" ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint --init --config '/tflint/path/to/config/config.tflint.hcl'   

docker run -it -v "$(pwd):/tflint" ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint --config '/tflint/path/to/config/config.tflint.hcl' '/tflint/path/to/terraform/code'
```

Which outputs:

```
Installing `azurerm` plugin...
Installed `azurerm` (source: github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm, version: 0.15.0)
Failed to initialize plugins; Plugin `azurerm` not found. Did you run `tflint --init`?
```

I know this is creating a new container on each run which is why it's not detecting its been initialized already - My question is how can I reuse this container to pass the extra args it requires after initializing it? Or is there a better way of doing so? Any input/feedback would be appreciated :) Thank you!

*Note: Here is the Dockerfile TFLint uses*

```
FROM golang:1.18.1-alpine3.15 as builder

RUN apk add --no-cache make

WORKDIR /tflint
COPY . /tflint
RUN make build

FROM alpine:3.15.4 as prod

LABEL maintainer=terraform-linters

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates

COPY --from=builder /tflint/dist/tflint /usr/local/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["tflint"]
WORKDIR /data
```

Comment: Running multiple commands in succession in a container normally means writing a script containing the commands, mounting it into the container (or creating a custom containerfile in which the script is copied to the image), and override the entrypoint to call the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change entrypoint to `sh` and pass multiple commands

`docker run -it -v "$(pwd):/tflint" --entrypoint=/bin/sh ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint -c "tflint --init --config '/tflint/path/to/config/config.tflint.hcl'; tflint --config '/tflint/path/to/config/config.tflint.hcl' '/tflint/path/to/terraform/code'"`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer it's much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dedicated Dockerfile that uses the tflint base image `ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint` and copy your files.
Something like:

```
FROM ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint

COPY <my files>

RUN tflint --init .......
```

It is just an example to give you an idea. Then you build it locally:

`docker build -t mytflint .`

And use your built image:

`docker run mytflint ......`

Comment: Also works - Thanks Sergio much appreciated :)

Comment: Hey if it helps, please consider upvote, mark as answered, etc etc thanks,